# Creating Multable pyGTK objects based on a list

Tags: python, string, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to create multable pyGtk objects with different names based on a list

```
    for objects in object_list:
        self.'%s'_entry % objects.upper() = gtk.Entry(max=0) 
        self.vbox_entry.add(self.'%s'_entry % objects.upper())
```

File "gtk test.py", line 113
    self.'%s'_entry % objects.upper() = gtk.Entry(max=0) 
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Is this possible. If not is there another way to do what i want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier and just use a list.

```
self.entries = [gtk.Entry(max=0) for objects in object_list]
for entry in self.entries:
  self.vbox_entry.add(entry)
```

Comment: Yes, but you should avoid dynamic attribute names when possible.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can get by just fine without having a special name for your widgets. When you retrieve them from their container, you can just recapitulate the order that you inserted them. If you really must have a name for them, you can use the `Widget.set_name()` method. I think this is more for CSS-theming purposes but I don't see why you can't use this for keeping track of what's what.